# Custom view in Dialog Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog, android-gui

How can I set a customize the style in extended DialogPreference ?

```
public class AboutDialog extends DialogPreference {
    public AboutDialog(Context oContext, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(oContext,attrs);
            //there is no such a thing like setBackground(int res_id)...
    }
}
```

and in the xml

```
<com.pak1.pak.About
    android:key="key" android:title="@string/preferences_about"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/preferences_about_title"
    android:dialogIcon="@drawable/app_icon" android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@string/ok" />
```

or for example is it possible to change properties of the button ?

I have one ok button, and for example I want to change the color of this 'ok' button, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You override onCreateDialogView, and return the layout.

See for instance this example by Matthew Wiggins for creating a custom DialogPreference.

http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-seekbar-preference

or here at stackoverflow

[Android SeekBarPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050272/android-seekbarpreference)

Answer (score 0):

To set background of DialogPreference you can also use method

```
    DialogPreference.setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.layout1);
```

and simple color resources, specified usually inside `res/values/colors.xml`:

```
    <color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
```

Refer to this resource via `android:background="@color/red"` in `res/layout/layout1.xml`.
([More info about setting a background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378716/1429387))