# Pop-up and seekbar in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have seen apps that have pop-ups (if you click "*Open Source License*" on the settings of Google Play) and seekbar (usually for volume and fontsize) in settings of some apps.

How are these implemented? In the res/xml/pref.xml file, I can only add the following components:

1. CheckBoxPreference
2. EditBoxPreference
3. ListPreference
4. RingtonePreference
5. AppWidgetProvider
6. Searchable

None of them seems to have a pop-up or seekbar.

I am building an app based on API 10 btw.i tried to read the guide and api but they are api 16 based and use lots of fragments,which is not available on APIs prior to Honeycomb.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popups can be coded by extending the [DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html). Create a custom Preference which will extend the DialogPreference for showing dialogs.

For Seekbar preference, go through this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050272/android-seekbarpreference) question. I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a `SeekBarPreference` myself according to Android's `EditTextPreference` implementation, which pops up a dialog containing a `SeekBar`. Feel free to use it.

https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/SeekBarPreference

Answer (score 1):

1) Make your `Activity` a `PreferenceActivity`.  ([PreferenceActivity tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html))

2) EditTextPreference will show up as a pop-up dialog by default.

3) For using `SeekBar` as a pop-up, I used a 3rd party library - [Aniqroid](http://code.google.com/p/aniqroid/)

Also refer: UX [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html) for designing `Settings` screen.

Happy Coding!