# Android seekbarpreference and display value

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences

I am trying to make a cusotm SeekBarPreference and display the value of it to the user. Each time I click on Settings in the menu, my app crashes and I'm not sure why. Here is the code I have so far.

MainActivity.java

```
//Within the MainActivity.java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.preferences:
            Intent i2 = new Intent("com.example.testApp.PREFERENCES");
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

res/xml/preferences.xml

Is it correct to use "com.example.testApp.SeekBarPreference" to call a new class?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
<com.example.testApp.SeekBarPreference
    android:title="Sensativity"
    android:key="seekbar"
    android:max="100"
    android:defaultValue="50">
</SeekBarPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

preferences.java

```
public class preferences extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

SeekBarPreference.java

I never get the log "In SBP!" since the app crashes. I left the stubs and haven't filled in the rest of the code here since I can't get to the log.

```
public class SeekBarPreference extends Preference implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
{

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        Log.i("SBP", "In SBP!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {     
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Helpful question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050272/android-seekbarpreference

Comment: Would be great if you post your logcat in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured this out long ago, but your opening and closing tags in your XML preference file are mismatched:

`<com.example.testApp.SeekBarPreference>
</SeekBarPreference>`

should be

`<com.example.testApp.SeekBarPreference>
</com.example.testApp.SeekBarPreference>`